# Bloomberg chat API?

Tags: bloomberg

Is there any API to send Bloomberg chat messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean to chat on a bloomberg terminal?  I don't think it exists. I did see a helpdesk chat on their website once, but nothing that lets you communicate with other terminal users.  They charge alot of money and I know guys who use their terminals only for access to the chat and network who use it.  All the big shots from the ceo of citi to the chairman of hilton hotels to even Tim Geithner..I don't think its likely bloomberg would open that chat to the outside work or outside their platform.

Comment: Traders wanted to exchange colors but didn't want to have yet another desktop app running. We decided to go with MS Messanger.

Comment: I used to work at two of the largest trading houses in the world(and one smaller one afteR), and in addition to bloomberg chat many traders used MSN or AOL so it works. Glad to hear it worked out

Answer (score 2):

They don't actively provide that, however I found a 'solution'. What I do is activate my VBA and do:

```
App.Activate "IB - IB Manager"
Application.Sendkeys "Hello, world"
Application.Sendkeys "~"
```

This e.g. allows me to automatically quote prices into Bloomberg IB chats.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, no, there is currently not support within the [bloomberg API](https://data.bloomberglp.com/labs/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf) to access the chat function (What Bloomberg calls IB - Instant Bloomberg).

If you have a terminal - or equivalent subscription, which is required to work with the API, you can hit **WAPI** and it will guide you through the SDK and what options exist.

The only options I know of for automatically sending some information through a chat box (which can be opened in a distinct window) is to pull it into focus and use ctypes or SendKeys in Python (or equivalents in other languages) to send the information you wanted to because you can tab between the contact/start chat and the text area within an open IB Manager box.

Let me know if you need any examples.

Some additional color on [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307904/sending-message-email-using-bloomberg-api?rq=1)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307904/sending-message-email-using-bloomberg-api?rq=1)