# sending message/email using Bloomberg API

Tags: api, bloomberg

Is there a way to send email or message using Bloomberg API?

We currently doing this via keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

No, since it's not documented in the Developer Guide:

http://www.bloomberglabs.com/content/uploads/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf

Another place where you can try to find hidden features is in XLTP function on the Terminal. But you won't find this one there.

What you can try is to bring the Terminal window to the foregroud and use SendKeys to send the keystrokes to send the MSG. I expect this would be slow and unreliable. You can improve on this by calling macros that you've defined on the terminal that save you from sending some key strokes.

Comment: Thank you. I sent email to bloomberg tech team. Wonder what they will say.

Comment: I have task to send "runs" messages to bloomberg users and have them recoginzed. Doesnt work when you send from non-bloomberg email (outlook).

Comment: I expect they'll say it's not supported. Why can't you send from a known external email address? Your users should recognize it if you always send from the same address.

Comment: Well we are sending to clients clients and want to use one "noreply" email or something like that.